# Modifying CKEditor toolbar at runtime

Tags: javascript

We have a requirement that our standard CKEditor toolbar omit a specific button on only one content type. It seems silly to create a brand new text format just for this. I'm able to modify the toolbar via a hook, but the modification gets saved and applied everywhere.

How can I programmatically modify the toolbar for just that content type?

Comment: Why exactly is it silly to create a separate Text Format for a specific use case? This is exactly why the capability to create new things through the UI exists. The Drupal way is always configuration over customization.

Comment: Because we need a default toolbar and this new one which is the same minus one button. By creating two text formats, any changes we would need in the future will need to be applied in two different places, vs my ideal solution of taking whatever the current toolbar is and removing the button we don't want

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this at the CKEditor level.  See:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html#defining-configuration-in-page

On the Drupal side, this JS could be added by altering the content type edit form to add the JS.

Comment: Thanks CG. Any idea how it'd work if the use case was actually a different Paragraph type? So same content type, but if user adds Paragraph type A they get default toolbar, but f user adds Paragraph type B, they get modified toolbar. Thanks